# Image does not float right

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML structure and CSS layout. My goal is to align the logo to the right side of the page but as of now, my solution does not work.

```css
#slide1 .logo {
  float: right;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="slide1">
  <img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg" />
</section>
```

Comment: It appears to be working, could you format your code so we have exactly what you have? https://jsfiddle.net/3Lapknqo/

Comment: From what you have provided, it obviously works: https://codepen.io/ron7/pen/RwavLYr if your setup contains additional CSS, please find a way to include it, so we can replicate your issue

Comment: No need for all the fiddles, people, we have [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: You should avoid using floats for layout. Learn about [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).